# Hide an element without masking item over top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, slidedown

I've created an effect whereby an HTML element is initially hidden behind another HTML element, and the CSS 'top' value of the hidden element is animated to expose it from beneath the masking element in a smooth sliding motion.

Does anyone know if there is a way to recreate this effect without the masking element on top?

I want to avoid the jQuery'esque slideDown where the height of the element being shown is animated.

I have the feeling that this just isn't possible, but if someone is otherwise aware, your advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you want to get rid of the masking element because it's offensive somehow; or if you want the masking element to merely *appear* to be absent. If the latter, then I would make a masking-element div whose background color is the same as the surrounding div's background color, such that the masked element seems to materialize from an invisible slot cut into the main background. BTW, thanks for the idea. That could be a very nice effect.

Comment: I understand that you want to avoid the slide-down business, but I think you could also, at the same time that **top** is changing,  animate the **height** of the masked element somehow, eliminating the masking element altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a wrapper that has `overflow` set to `hidden`

http://jsfiddle.net/xvNf6/1/

#### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:0px;">
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

#### Sample CSS

```
#wrapper{width:300px;height:280px;margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; background:#eee}
```

#### Javascript

```
//if you must not use jQuery
var animationTimer = setInterval(function(){
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    wrapper.style.height = (parseInt(wrapper.style.height) + 1) + "px";
    if(parseInt(wrapper.style.height) >= 280)
        clearInterval(animationTimer)
},1);
```

```
//if you can use jQuery
$("#wrapper").animate({height:"280px"},1000);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't want to adjust the height of the element I am exposing either. Imagine for example the element to be exposed is an image, so whereas resizing it would almost achieve the desired effect, the image would appear squashed. If that makes sense?

Comment: @Ashley that's the point of the overflow:hidden div.  With that, it doesn't resize anything but instead cuts it all off.

Answer (score 0):

Place your element within a parent div with `overflow:hidden`. Then, position your element beyond bounds of the parent div so that it is hidden.

```
#wrapper { overflow: hidden; }
#target { height: 100px; top: -100px; } /* shift element out of view */
```

You can then reveal it by animating to `{"top":0}` to get the slidedown effect that doesn't resize the height of the element.

Here's a rather crude demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7RSWZ/

**Update**: Here's another demo that attempts to deal better with different content sizes by dynamically setting the heights and `top` values. http://jsfiddle.net/7RSWZ/2/